# Extra key in discriminated object not being recognized by conditional type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make an object, where if the status is "ok" then the "data" key is not present, unless the type was instantiated with a generic for `TData`.

I tried the following:

```
type TStatusObject<TData = never> =
  | { status: 'idle' }
  | { status: 'loading' }
  | { status: 'error'; }
  | (TData extends never ? { status: 'ok', data?: never } : { status: 'ok'; data: TData });

const fooStatus: TStatusObject = { status: 'ok' };
```

However I get error here saying:

> Type '"ok"' is not assignable to type '"idle" | "loading" | "error"'.ts(2322)
> status-object.ts(4, 7): The expected type comes from property 'status' which is declared here on type 'TStatusObject'

Any ideas on why this is happening? It seems so simple.

Comment: `TDate extends never ? ⋯ : ⋯` is a distributive conditional type. If `F<T>` is a distributive conditional type, then `F<A | B | C>` is evaluated as `F<A> | F<B> | F<C>` and `F<never>` is evaluated as `never`. See the linked q/a for more information.